# $N(A^T) \subset N(B^T)$ and the system $Bx=b$ has at least one solution, then the system $Ax=b$ has at least one solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ be a $m \times k$ matrix such that $N(A^T) \subset N(B^T)$ and the system $Bx=b$ has at least one solution, then the system $Ax=b$ has at least one solution, where $b \in \Bbb R^m$.

Facing difficulty to prove this, hints required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [fundamental theorem of linear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_linear_algebra) (see also [this](http://home.engineering.iastate.edu/~julied/classes/CE570/Notes/strangpaper.pdf) wonderful article by Gilbert Strang). In particular, note that
$$
N(C^T)=R(C)^\perp
$$
for any matrix $C$, the assumption $N(A^T)\subset N(B^T)$ tells you that
$$
R(A)^\perp\subset R(B)^\perp
$$
and thus
$$
R(B)\subset R(A)
$$
which is exactly your conclusion.

Note that the notation $N(C)$ corresponds to $\ker (C)$ and $R(C)$ is $\text{im}(C)$ in the Wikipedia page. Also, saying that "$Ax=b$ has (at least) one solution" is exactly the same as saying that $b$ is in the range of $A$, i.e., $b\in R(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $Ker(A) = Im^\perp(A^T)$ and $V \subseteq W \implies W^\perp \subseteq V^\perp$.